# translating named list vectors from R into rpy2 in Python?

Tags: python, r, rpy2

What is the equivalent of the following R code in Rpy2 in python?

```
Var1 = c("navy", "darkgreen")
names(Var1) = c("Class1", "Class2")
ann_colors = list(Var1 = Var1)
```

It's not clear what `ann_colors` is. When evaluated in R it gives:

```
> ann_colors
$Var1
     Class1      Class2 
     "navy" "darkgreen"
```

Is it an `robject.ListVector`? I tried:

```
robjects.ListVector({"Class1": "navy", "Class2": "green"})
```

but it's not quite it because I'm not sure how to tell the ListVector object that the name of this object is `Var1`, i.e. something like `list(Var1 = Var1)`.

How can this be properly translated to rpy2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After many hours of trial and error, I found the solution. I don't fully understand why the similar variants of this did not work, or why this scheme is not interchangeable with dataframes, but what I got to work is:

```
anno_colors = robj.StrVector(tuple(["navy", "green"]))
anno_colors.names = ["Class1", "Class2"]
od = OrderedDict()
od["Type"] = anno_colors
result = robj.ListVector(od)
print str(result)
```

Answer (score 7):

If I understand right your question what you are looking for is a TaggedList:

```
import rpy2.rlike.container as rlc
Var1 = rlc.TaggedList(["navy","darkgreen"], tags=('Class1', 'Class2'))
```

See http://rpy.sourceforge.net/rpy2/doc-2.2/html/rlike.html for more details.

Comment: But `ann_colors` in my example adds additional information about `Var1`, i.e. that `Var1` is the holder of the navy/green, Class1/Class2 information. Not sure how that is expressed in TaggedList?

Comment: @user248237dfsf The idea behind the `TaggedList` was to provide something similar to an R named vector: each item in the list has a tag (name). The difference with an `OrderedDict` is that names are not unique.